# PHP Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property WPSC_Cart::$log_id is deprecated

Tags: php, dynamic, properties, warnings, deprecated

Have just upgraded to PHP 8.2 after fixing some of these dynamic property deprecated warnings.

Thought all had been addressed, by found one remaining from the error logs after upgrading, which am struggling to fix.

Still quite new to php, so could be that I'm missing something obvious.

The reason I'm struggling is because there is no mention of a class in any of the php code in this file, which with all the other dynamic property warnings, appeared just above the function, which could be easily fixed by adding e.g:

```
public $log_id;
```

The code below relating to this error:

```
function wpsc_submit_checkout( $collected_data = true ) {
global $wpdb, $wpsc_cart, $user_ID, $nzshpcrt_gateways, $wpsc_shipping_modules, $wpsc_gateways;

if ( $collected_data && isset( $_POST['collected_data'] ) && is_array( $_POST['collected_data'] ) ) {
    _wpsc_checkout_customer_meta_update( $_POST['collected_data'] );
}

// initialize our checkout status variable, we start be assuming
// checkout is falid, until we find a reason otherwise
$is_valid           = true;
$num_items          = 0;
$use_shipping       = 0;
$disregard_shipping = 0;

do_action( 'wpsc_before_submit_checkout', $collected_data );

$error_messages = wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'checkout_misc_error_messages' );

if ( ! is_array( $error_messages ) ) {
    $error_messages = array();
}

$wpsc_checkout = new wpsc_checkout();

$selected_gateways = get_option( 'custom_gateway_options' );
$submitted_gateway = isset( $_POST['custom_gateway'] ) ? $_POST['custom_gateway'] : '';

if ( $collected_data ) {
    $form_validity = $wpsc_checkout->validate_forms();
    extract( $form_validity ); // extracts $is_valid and $error_messages

    if ( wpsc_has_tnc() && ( ! isset( $_POST['agree'] ) || $_POST['agree'] != 'yes' ) ) {
        $error_messages[] = __( 'Please agree to the terms and conditions, otherwise we cannot process your order.', 'wp-e-commerce' );
        $is_valid = false;
    }
} else {
    $is_valid = true;
    $error_messages = array();
}

if ( wpsc_uses_shipping() ) {
    $wpsc_country = new WPSC_Country( wpsc_get_customer_meta( 'shippingcountry' ) );
    $country_id   = $wpsc_country->get_id();
    $country_name = $wpsc_country->get_name();

    foreach ( $wpsc_cart->cart_items as $cartitem ) {

        if ( ! empty( $cartitem->meta[0]['no_shipping'] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $category_ids = $cartitem->category_id_list;

        foreach ( (array) $category_ids as $catid ) {
            if ( is_array( $catid ) ) {
                $countries = wpsc_get_meta( $catid[0], 'target_market', 'wpsc_category' );
            } else {
                $countries = wpsc_get_meta( $catid, 'target_market', 'wpsc_category' );
            }

            if ( ! empty( $countries ) && ! in_array( $country_id, (array) $countries ) ) {
                $errormessage = sprintf( __( '%s cannot be shipped to %s. To continue with your transaction, please remove this product from the list below.', 'wp-e-commerce' ), $cartitem->get_title(), $country_name );
                wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'category_shipping_conflict', $errormessage );
                $is_valid = false;
            }
        }

        //count number of items, and number of items using shipping
        $num_items++;

        if ( $cartitem->uses_shipping != 1 ) {
            $disregard_shipping++;
        } else {
            $use_shipping++;
        }
    }
}

// check to see if the current gateway is in the list of available gateways
if ( array_search( $submitted_gateway, $selected_gateways ) !== false || wpsc_is_free_cart() ) {
    wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'selected_gateway', $submitted_gateway );
} else {
    $is_valid = false;
}

if ( $collected_data ) {

    // Test for required shipping information
    if ( wpsc_core_shipping_enabled() && ( $num_items != $disregard_shipping ) ) {
        // for shipping to work we need a method, option and a quote, unless we have free shipping.

        $shipping_discount_value  = get_option( 'shipping_discount_value' );
        $is_free_shipping_enabled = get_option( 'shipping_discount' );
        $subtotal                 = $wpsc_cart->calculate_subtotal();

        $has_free_shipping = $is_free_shipping_enabled && $shipping_discount_value > 0 && $shipping_discount_value <= $subtotal;

        if ( ! $has_free_shipping ) {
            if ( ! $wpsc_cart->shipping_method_selected() || ! $wpsc_cart->shipping_quote_selected() ) {
                $error_messages[] = __( 'Please select one of the available shipping options, then we can process your order.', 'wp-e-commerce' );
                $is_valid = false;
            }
        }

        // if we don't have a valid zip code ( the function also checks if we need it ) we have an error
        if ( ! wpsc_have_valid_shipping_zipcode() ) {
                wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'category_shipping_conflict', __( 'Please enter a Zipcode and click calculate to proceed', 'wp-e-commerce' ) );
                $is_valid = false;
        }
    }
}

wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'checkout_misc_error_messages', $error_messages );

if ( $is_valid == true ) {
    wpsc_delete_customer_meta( 'category_shipping_conflict' );
    // check that the submitted gateway is in the list of selected ones
    $sessionid = (mt_rand( 100, 999 ) . time());
    wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'checkout_session_id', $sessionid );
    $subtotal = $wpsc_cart->calculate_subtotal();
    if ( $wpsc_cart->has_total_shipping_discount() == false )
        $base_shipping = $wpsc_cart->calculate_base_shipping();
    else
        $base_shipping = 0;

    $delivery_country = $wpsc_cart->delivery_country;
    $delivery_region = $wpsc_cart->delivery_region;

    if ( wpsc_uses_shipping() ) {
        $shipping_method = $wpsc_cart->selected_shipping_method;
        $shipping_option = $wpsc_cart->selected_shipping_option;
    } else {
        $shipping_method = '';
        $shipping_option = '';
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['how_find_us'] ) )
        $find_us = $_POST['how_find_us'];
    else
        $find_us = '';

    //keep track of tax if taxes are exclusive
    $wpec_taxes_controller = new wpec_taxes_controller();
    if ( ! $wpec_taxes_controller->wpec_taxes_isincluded() ) {
        $tax = $wpsc_cart->calculate_total_tax();
        $tax_percentage = $wpsc_cart->tax_percentage;
    } else {
        $tax = 0.00;
        $tax_percentage = 0.00;
    }

    $total = $wpsc_cart->calculate_total_price();

    $args = array(
        'totalprice'       => $total,
        'statusno'         => '0',
        'sessionid'        => $sessionid,
        'user_ID'          => (int) $user_ID,
        'date'             => time(),
        'gateway'          => $submitted_gateway,
        'billing_country'  => $wpsc_cart->selected_country,
        'shipping_country' => $delivery_country,
        'billing_region'   => $wpsc_cart->selected_region,
        'shipping_region'  => $delivery_region,
        'base_shipping'    => $base_shipping,
        'shipping_method'  => $shipping_method,
        'shipping_option'  => $shipping_option,
        'plugin_version'   => WPSC_VERSION,
        'discount_value'   => $wpsc_cart->coupons_amount,
        'discount_data'    => $wpsc_cart->coupons_name,
        'find_us'          => $find_us,
        'wpec_taxes_total' => $tax,
        'wpec_taxes_rate'  => $tax_percentage,
    );

    $purchase_log = new WPSC_Purchase_Log( $args );
    $purchase_log->save();
    $purchase_log_id = $purchase_log->get( 'id' );

    //Check to ensure log row was inserted successfully
    if(is_null($purchase_log_id)) {
        $error_messages[] = __( 'A database error occurred while processing your request.', 'wp-e-commerce' );
        wpsc_update_customer_meta( 'checkout_misc_error_messages', $error_messages );
        return;
    }

    if ( $collected_data ) {
        $wpsc_checkout->save_forms_to_db( $purchase_log_id );
    }

    $wpsc_cart->save_to_db( $purchase_log_id );
    $wpsc_cart->submit_stock_claims( $purchase_log_id );

    if ( ! isset( $our_user_id ) && isset( $user_ID ) ) {
        $our_user_id = $user_ID;
    }

    $wpsc_cart->log_id = $purchase_log_id;
    do_action( 'wpsc_submit_checkout', array( 'purchase_log_id' => $purchase_log_id, 'our_user_id' => $our_user_id ) );
    do_action( 'wpsc_submit_checkout_gateway', $submitted_gateway, $purchase_log );
}
```

}

This is the line of code relating to the above error:

```
    $wpsc_cart->log_id = $purchase_log_id;
```

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated!

Comment: You would need to find out what class `$wpsc_cart` is an instance of, try `echo get_class($wpsc_cart);` you then need to add the property to that class.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, managed to find out what class $wpsc_cart was an instance of by going through some of the other files. Added public $log_id; to the other file, and this has resolved the issue. Appreciate your help on this.